# How to set state of component in Signalr connection.on()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, signalr

I want to get data from server with signalr and update content of React component. Everything is ok. Data is received from the server BUT state of component could not update (undefined).

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ToastComponent } from '@syncfusion/ej2-react-notifications';
import * as signalR from '@aspnet/signalr';


class Notification extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super(...arguments);
        this.position = { X: 'Right', Y: 'Top' }
        this.state = { message:null}

    }

    toastCreated() {
        this.toastInstance.show({ timeOut:0 })
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        const notifConn = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/notif").build();
        notifConn.on("ReceiveMessage", function (msg) {
            this.setState = ({ message: msg })

        });
        notifConn.start().then(function () {
            notifConn.invoke("SendNotification");

        }).catch(function (er) {
            console.log(er.toString());
        });


    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setState` is a function, so

```
this.setState = ({ message: msg })
```

Should instead be

```
this.setState({ message: msg })
```

Besides, your function will not be able to access your classe's `this`. So instead of a normal anonymous function, you should go with an arrow function that preserves the context:

```
notifConn.on("ReceiveMessage", (msg) => {
   this.setState({ message: msg })
});
```

Comment: I have a similar issue. The difference is that I need to render a second component (modal) when the message arrives.

`render() {
    const { msg, open } = this.state;
    return (
      <div><Modal msg={msg} open={open} /></div>
    );
  }`

`class Modal ... {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { open: this.props.open };
  }

  render() {
    const { classes, msg} = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <Modal open={this.state.open} onClose={this.close}>
            <p>{msg}</p>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Can you write your constructor this way:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.position = { X: 'Right', Y: 'Top' }
    this.state = { message:null}

}
```

and  use this for changing the state: `this.setState({message:msg})`

Answer (score 0):

You should do it by this way...

```
this.setState({ message: msg })
```

setState is a function which modifies the current state of the component's variable and force component to re-render the result.
Although you can do it like (**Strongly Not Recommended**)

```
this.state.message = msg;
```

But this will not inform component to re-render.